# Unity Canvas blocking objects in Editor

Tags: unity, gui

I think I am missing something really basic here..., I'm creating a 2D game in unity, and the UI Canvas (with the setting "Screen Space - Overlay") is blocking exactly a quarter of my workspace. I can not select any objects on the top right part of the screen.

Is there any fix to this?, or do I have to move the camera down half of the screen?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the canvas and move it back or forwards along the Z axis.

Comment: Woo!, didn't think about the third axis :D THANKS!

Comment: Glad to help! :)

Comment: how did you do this??? Position values in the Rect Transform component are grayed out! :(

Answer (score 5):

**`Layers`** *(top-right of editor)* > **`UI`** > **`Lock Layer for Picking`** *(the little padlock)*

This will allow any clicks to go through the canvas and reach whatever's behind!

[image: Lock Layer for Picking]